# How to display the user entered text on the same screen

Tags: android

I'm a begineer in android. I learned from the developer.android.com, how to display a text by calling another activity. I want to display the user entered text in the same window. i.e., belolow the text field(center). please anyone help me. I'm a beginner in android and I have just started to learn android.

Comment: share the code that you done so far...

Comment: There are many ways to do it,hence you show us your code and we will help you to solve your error in one single proper way :)

Comment: I just posted answer but plz place your code here so we will help you better way..

Answer (score 0):

**you can display value in to label using .setText() or you can use Toast**

write this inside your button OnClick Event Listner

Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Plain Text Input: " + editTextPlainTextInput.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

->  **MainActivity.this** is your context

->**editTextPlainTextInput.getText().toString()** is value entered by user gettext() gets value and .toString() convert this to string because Toast not accept Object.

-> **Toast.LENGTH_SHORT** is time that how long toast message appears

Answer (score 0):

Use EditText to get user input text

```
EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

For use of the TextWatcher listen text field

```
text .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

use onTextChanged method to use listen to edittext . Then inside onTextChanged  start another activity  passing  that test value